# Swift UserDefault - Store a large object?

Tags: swift, swift3

In my `UserDefaults` I need to store "favorites" saved by the user. Each of the favorite contains a name and a phonenumber.

Running a list of contacts later needs to check for every contact if the contact already is favorited.

Anyway, looking at storing a object in `UserDefaults` it seems like a big hassle? I would like something more easy. Any inputs on how to do this?

I was thinking maybe storing it as a long string comma and underscore seperated. Like "`Name_Phone`, `Name2_Phone2`"

And then splitting it into an array for access later by comma and underscore.

Though, I'm worried some names may have comma or underscore in it.

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: Maybe a Dictionnary? something like that `let favorites: [String : String] = favorites["Fav1"] = "Name_Phone"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` is for small data and attributes. However for big data like these, the best approach is to use the native **Core-Data** that is designed to fit exactly what you need.

I suggest you to use this library that is built on core data: https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore

Comment: there are options between `UserDefault` and __CoreData__ for such job, like how about `.plists`?

Comment: .plists is an answer as well! However I tend to use core data since it's more flexible and dynamic.

Comment: don't get me wrong, I won't argue against CoreData but every task requires such brutal resources to store list of `String` objects; even when something is better from devs' perspective, it does not mean it is better from the perspective of the actual project's architecture :)